# Background Fetch Enumerations

Tags: ios, background, fetch

In iOS the outcome of a background fetch could be one of the following:

1. `UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData`
2. `UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData`
3. `UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed`

In what way does iOS care about the outcome?

I understand that a fetch that lasts too long (I believe 30 secs or more) is penalized by giving less fetch opportunities to the app.

Does any of the above, specifically `NoData` and `Failed` have repercussions as well?
Or is this just for internal processing?

Why not just return `UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData` every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precise algorithm used by Apple is not described, but in the [iOS Application Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5) Apple states,

> Apps that download small amounts of content quickly, and accurately reflect when they had content available to download, are more likely to receive execution time in the future than apps that take a long time to download their content or that claim content was available but then do not download anything.

It seems that iOS observes your app's behaviour.  If it claimed that new content was available (returned `UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData`) but it did not actually perform a network operation it may receive less frequent background fetch opportunities.  It pays to be honest.

I also seem to remember reading somewhere (but can't find a reference now) that iOS can use the completion value to determine the times of day when your server may have new content (For example, if the fetch around 1am consistently returns new data and the fetch at 6pm consistently doesn't, iOS may be more likely to perform a background fetch for your app at 1am).

You should aim to complete the fetch as quickly as possible, but do not call the completion handler until the fetch is complete or your app will be suspended without completing the download.  You can also use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` to get more time, but your app has a limit of 180 seconds, total, of background execution per 'backgrounding' (ie. If the user brings your app back to the foreground and then suspends it again the 180 seconds is reset).

Comment: So, if the completion handler is called, and some async stuff is still going on, the fetch is considered as a cheat, and won't be called in the future?

Comment: No, if the completion handler is called and some async stuff is still going on then your app will be suspended and the async stuff will stop without being completed.

Comment: That is not what I'm seeing: I have a Login method that returns a UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData, but continues to actually load data. These methods are finished after the completion handler is called. It would need some refactoring to make sure the completion handler is called when everything is finished, I realize that, but it is working for me now. And I understand, that this would be without penalties, right?

Comment: If it is working for you, then that's fine. I have seen people have problems if the call the completion handler before they are done. I can't guarantee that you won't be penalized since the actual algorithm is only known by Apple